# Security Question AuraEnabled Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, security, aura, lightning-web-components

Let's say I have an Apex Class like this:

```
public with sharing class AuraUtils {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<SObject> databaseQuery(String queryString){
    List<SObject> returnValue;
    try{
        returnValue = Database.query(queryString);
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

}

and a Lightning Web Component like this:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import databaseQuery from '@salesforce/apex/AuraUtils.databaseQuery';

export default class UtilityDemo extends LightningElement {

    @wire(databaseQuery, {queryString: '$accountQueryString'})
    accounts;

    get accountQueryString () {
        return "SELECT Id, Name, Phone, (SELECT Id , FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 20";
    }
}
```

Is this safe? Can a client use something like this to inject SOQL statements and do nefarious things? My thought is that since the method is wired to use the `accountQueryString` and the getter for that is defined I should be relatively safe....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users can technically modify any client code. You've taken a step in the right direction by using `with sharing` to prevent users from seeing *records* they don't have access to. The only flaw with your plan so far is that a malicious user could try to query *fields* they don't have access to. You would probably want to add some security by injecting '[WITH SECURITY_ENABLED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm)' in to the query, which would cause an exception if one or more fields are not allowed. I haven't specifically written something like this as of yet, but it'd probably be something along the lines of:

```
queryString = queryString.replaceFirst('\\s+FROM\\s+(.+?)\\s+', ' FROM $1 WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED ');
```

This should cause the queries to be properly FLS-enforced (or throw an exception if users try to get clever by inserting a random space in a sub-query).

Comment: You mean `with sharing` right?

Comment: @javanoob Oops, yes, that's what I meant.